# Current site URL in Liferay 6.2

Tags: url, liferay

I cannot figure out how to get URL of current site in Liferay. For example if i have created four **sites** - site1, site2, site3, site4. URL of this sites will be:

```
http://localhost:8080/web/site1/
http://localhost:8080/web/site2/
http://localhost:8080/web/site3/
http://localhost:8080/web/site4/
```

But how can i get this URLs from velocity (in theme)? I tried few options:

```
$themeDisplay.getPathFriendlyURLPublic() - /web
$themeDisplay.getPortalURL()             - http://localhost:8080
$themeDisplay.getURLHome()               - http://localhost:8080/web/guest
$themeDisplay.getURLCurrent()            - /web/site1/home
```

I need to get just `http://localhost:8080/web/actualsite/`.

Comment: Use `$themeDisplay.getPortalURL()+$themeDisplay.getScopeGroup().getPathFriendlyURL(false,$themeDisplay)`

Comment: I tried that, but it is not right solution (it returned just '/web'). I found right solution (displayed below).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All right, after few hours of trying I find solution:

To get current site url, you need to use:

**$layout.getGroup().friendlyURL** in velocity.

This expression returns **'/site-name'** format.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your theme vm. This should give you current complete url.

```
$portalUtil.getCurrentCompleteURL($request)

Output : http://localhost:8080/web/site4/home
```

Comment: As I have written - i need url without 'home' part. And I have found solution already (below). Thank you.